# Complex numbers as linear operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

If it is valid to interpret multiplication by a complex number as a dilative rotation, does that mean that it can be viewed as a function $$f: R^2 \rightarrow R^2$$

making it a linear operator?

Comment: Well, not all functions on $\Bbb R^2$ are linear operators, but yes, dilation/rotations are linear operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A complex number $a + ib$ corresponds to a linear map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given, in the standard basis, by the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix}.$$

A generic real $2 \times 2$ matrix (i.e., a real-linear map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$) has this form if and only if the corresponding map is *complex*-linear, in which case, after identification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$, it is simply multiplication by $a+ib$.